# Split big class into smaller classes

Tags: java, arrays, refactoring

I need help to split this code into different classes. 
This class generate an array from random numbers and get the max and the min of the array.
I am intended to make more functions on it (a lot of them) but I dont want everything in the main class. ¿How can I do it with this, and with the next that I am going to do?

```
package ejercicioarrays;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class EjercicioArrays {

public void main(String[] args) {
    //vector con las notas generadas
    int[] control = new int[20];
    int maxNota = 0;
    int minNota = 0;
    int indMaxNota, indMinNota;
    int postEval;
    //Genera notas random entre 1 y 10
    for(int i=0; i < control.length; i++){
        control[i] = (int)(Math.random()*11);
    }
    //buscamos al mayor
    postEval = 11;
    for(int i=0; i<control.length; i++){
        int preEval = control[i];
        if (preEval < postEval){
            minNota = preEval;
            postEval = control[i];
        }
    }
    //buscamos al menor
    postEval = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<control.length; i++){
        int preEval = control[i];
        if (preEval > postEval){
            maxNota = preEval;
            postEval = control[i];
        }
    }
//Comprobamos el resultado del ejercicio   
System.out.println("Mínimo es: " + minNota);
System.out.println("Máximo es: " + maxNota); 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(control)); 

}
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is maybe a better place to ask

Comment: I presume you mean "main method" rather than "main class".

Comment: I think JDK8 and lambdas would be a better, cleaner way to do this.

Comment: If you want to go the class route, then this sentence is the key: This class generate an array from random numbers and get the max and the min of the array. I see a class that generates an arrat and provides a min and max method.  However, OO is not necessarily the cleanest way to solve this problem.

Comment: I suggest your extract methods using the refactoring in your IDE.  Then you can put these methods in different methods if you want to. I would have a class which wraps `control` for example.